# Windows Phone Emulator exited with code 8 during Cordova Multi Device Hybrid App Build

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

While building a Cordova Multi Device Hybrid App for windows phone, it is throwing an error.

```
Error message : The command ""C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows Phone" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "AngularJSToDo" --language "en-US" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "PhoneEmulatorWvga512"" exited with code 8.
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets 99  5   AngularJSToDo
```

But it is working fine for Android and iphone. Issue is only with Windows phone.

Comment: Have the same error message for Windows Phone and Android, couldn't test iPhone myself ...

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the required SDKs are not installed on your machine. To resolve this, go to:

- Programs and Features
- Right click on Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
- Click change
- Choose Modify
- Check "Tools for Maintaining Store Apps for Windows 8" and Windows Phone 8.0 SDK"
- Click Update

That should install the missing SDK. Then try building again after restarting Visual Studio.

Taken from the official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx).

Comment: I have followed these steps but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Could you check if you have Hyper-v enabled on your machine?

Comment: Yes i have Hyper-v enabled. My windows 8.1 emulator is working fine. The error only happens when i try to run the Hybrid app.

Comment: Could you try this with a blank app?